# ResultSet metadata .getcolumnname

Tags: java, jdbc

I m trying to get all field/column names of a result set. code has been pasted below.  it returns an error [The cursor type/concurrency combination is not supported].

```
SQL = dbConnectionSQLServer.getCN().prepareStatement("Select * From Coa32");
            RS = SQL.executeQuery();
            ResultSetMetaData metaData = RS.getMetaData();

            //Generate table header.
            for (int j = 0; j < RS.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); j++) {
//                System.out.println("Colum Count : " + metaData.getColumnCount() + ", Column Name (1) : " + metaData.getCatalogName(j));
                tableHeaderNames.add(new ColumnModel("header "+j, " col:"+ metaData.getColumnName(j)));


   }
```

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace and specify the database and driver you're using. Also, be aware that - depending on your needs - you may need to use `getColumnLabel` instead of `getColumnName`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    tableData = new ArrayList< Map<String, ColumnModel> >();
    tableHeaderNames = new ArrayList<ColumnModel>();
    Statement SQL = dbConnectionSQLServer.getCN().createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

    RS = SQL.executeQuery("Select * From Coa32");

    for (int j = 0; j < RS.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); j++) {
    System.out.println("Start:");
        tableHeaderNames.add(new ColumnModel("header "+j, " col:"+ RS.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(1)));
    System.out.println("End:");
    }
```

Found the solution in changing the type of statement to Senstive and updateable.

Comment: Please learn the technology you use. Plain jdbc problem, not a java-se or jsf problem

Comment: @Kukeltje More likely a driver bug, because the code as shown should work. I also think your removal of the Java tag was unwarranted, because JDBC is part of Java SE and the code shown is Java code.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: agreed, sorry. Have not been doing low level jdbc for long time and seen sooooo many jsf questions with the java tag wrongfully added that I removed it for that reason and forgot to leave it in related to jdbc